# What is PostgreSQL ANY/SOME syntax exactly?

Tags: postgresql

On documentation page
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-comparisons.html

ANY/SOME is described as follows:
`expression operator ANY (array expression)`

given the tables:

```
create table ints1(
    id int
);
create table arrays1(
    ints int[]
);
```

and queries:

```
select id from ints1 where id = any (array[1, 2]);
```

working, as expected, because the array literal syntax is explained here
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/arrays.html

```
select id from ints1 where id = any (select id from ints1 where id in (1, 2));
```

is working, but why?
so I thought maybe there is a smart type conversion from 1-column row set to array type and tried the following query:

```
insert into arrays1 (ints) values ( select id from ints1 );
```

not working - syntax error near select

then tried this:

```
insert into arrays1 (ints) values ( ARRAY(select id from ints1) );
```

this worked and inserted correct values into `arrays` table, but I did not found how ARRAY(..) expression should work in documentation.

I thought maybe ARRAY(..) is some type cast operator again, and tried to use `::int[]`:

```
insert into arrays1 (ints) values ( (select id from ints1)::int[] );
```

ERROR:  cannot cast type integer to integer[]

1. Can anyone point to place in documentation where `array expression` is defined
2. clarify why did 2nd query run ok and 3rd failed
3. clarify how ARRAY(..) expression works, and what's the difference with the type cast to `int[]`

Comment: [Array constructors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) and [Array Input and Output Syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-IO) in the manual

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name indeed, explains everything, except why the 2nd query works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check array constructor from subquery: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS

The second query works because one form of `any` accepts an array: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN21104

The subquery form of `any`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ANY-SOME

Comment: May be a valuable resource, but link-only answers aren't really an SO thing. If those is all you have perhaps a comment would be more appropriate.

Comment: can you please give a link to the other form of any? I could only find the form with `array expression`, thus the the whole topic arouse. And by second query I meant the query with nested select `= any (select ...)`

Comment: @MikhailBoyarsky: It is the posted one.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto sorry for unclarity, where is the _other_ one in documentation? The one you posted I mentioned in first post. Unable to find it by postgres documentation search and google.

Comment: @MikhailBoyarsky: Updated